# Can any of existing report portal agent be reused for k6?

Tags: k6, reportportal

We are using k6 in our project for load testing. As other teams uses report portal for pushing results. We also wanted to try the same.

It’ll be easier for Management to see from single UI.

There is no agent for K6 as of now.
But there are many agents for JavaScript. https://github.com/reportportal/examples-js

Can any of the agent be reused for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did not find any existing agent for k6 .So we wrote agent by ourselves.

https://github.com/SamPosh/agent-k6-reportportal

It solved the issue. I am recording for future user who might face the same problem